# Is there a difference in performance or capability in these sas cables?

Tags: storage, sas, cable

I'm looking at sas sff-8644 to sff-8088 cables and noticed that some are single cable where as others are dual cable.  What's the difference between these, and is one better when connecting an hba to an array than the other?

[image: dual cable]

[image: single cable]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those SAS cables run four SAS lanes. Whether they do so in one, two or four cables doesn't matter, that's merely cosmetic.

You should check the rated maximum speed though if your intend to use the cable for SAS-3 (12 Gbit/s) or possibly SAS-4 (22.5 Gbit/s).